Regular Expression to remove repeated words or numbers
I want TypeScript code which uses Regular Expression to first understand repeated words or numbers in a string (like '2024' or 'May') and then replace the first matched ones with empty.
Examples:
// Change '27 May 2024 - 02 Jun 2024'
// To '27 May - 02 Jun 2024'

// Change '20 May 2024 - 26 May 2024'
// To '20 - 26 May 2024'

Any generic regex which can do the above is so appreciated.
Thanks a heap :)

Regex isn't the right tool for this task.

What is holding you back to write your code for this?

With regex you need at least capture groups and backreference to match the same text again. E.g. search for ((?: \w+)? \d{4})\b( - [\w ]+\b\1\b) and replace with $2 (group 2 capture). Or use a lookahead and replace with emty string: ((?: \w+)? \d{4})\b(?= - [\w ]+\b\1\b)

Something like this would do:


function removeRepeatedWordsOrNumbers(input) {
    const regex = /\b(\d{1,2}) (\w+) (\d{4}) - (\d{1,2}) (\w+) \3\b/;
    const result = input.replace(regex, (_, day1, month1, year1, day2, month2) => {
        if (month1 === month2) {
            return `${day1} - ${day2} ${month1} ${year1}`;
        } else {
            return `${day1} ${month1} - ${day2} ${month2} ${year1}`;
        }
    });
    return result;
}


console.log(JSON.stringify(removeRepeatedWordsOrNumbers('27 May 2024 - 02 Jun 2024')));
console.log(JSON.stringify(removeRepeatedWordsOrNumbers('20 May 2024 - 26 May 2024')));
console.log(JSON.stringify(removeRepeatedWordsOrNumbers('01 January 2023 - 15 January 2023')));
console.log(JSON.stringify(removeRepeatedWordsOrNumbers('10 March 2025 - 20 April 2025')));
console.log(JSON.stringify(removeRepeatedWordsOrNumbers('27 May 2024 - 02 Jun 2024')));
console.log(JSON.stringify(removeRepeatedWordsOrNumbers('20 May 2024 - 26 May 2024')));
console.log(JSON.stringify(removeRepeatedWordsOrNumbers('20 Aug 2024 - 26 Aug 2025')));




Doesn't work correctly for lots of inputs, for example '27 May 2024 - 27 Jun 2024' and '20 May 2024 - 26 May 2025'

@GuyIncognito Why not check result of the given code it works perfectly.. What case are you specifically referring too?

I did check, and it didn't work correctly. I'm referring to the two cases I specified in my comment.

Specified case you mentioned in the comment doest appear to be the OP cases defined. @GuyIncognito

I think it's pretty safe to assume that the OP wants a method that works with all dates, not just the exact two cases they specified. Otherwise the answer would be simple: if(input == '27 May 2024 - 02 Jun 2024') return '27 May - 02 Jun 2024'; else if(input == '20 May 2024 - 26 May 2024') return '20 - 26 May 2024'; else throw Error("Invalid input!");

I got what you saying now.... I've updated the answer accordingly check now...
